# Error in model training - Exception encountered when calling layer 'model_1' (type Functional)

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, training-data

With the model training aspect I keep getting the same error, I don't know how I can fix it, I need a little help. This is a code and type of error:

`# Train the model model.fit([X_title_train, X_time_train], Y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2)`

I have mistake in the last one, and this is type of error:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'model_1' (type Functional).

Input 0 of layer "dense_3" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 65, but received input with shape (None, 66)

Call arguments received by layer 'model_1' (type Functional):
  • inputs=('tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 2), dtype=float64)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 2), dtype=float64)')
  • training=True
  • mask=None
```